# Sort the unique numbers in a multiplication table

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Pretty simple challenge today:

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N and prints or returns a ***sorted*** list of the ***unique*** numbers that appear in the [multiplication table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table) whose row and column multiplicands both range from 1 to N inclusive.

The list may be sorted in ascending order (smallest to largest) or descending order (largest to smallest), and may be output in any reasonable format.

**The shortest code in bytes wins!**

## Example

When N = 4, the multiplication table looks like:

```
   1  2  3  4
  -----------
1| 1  2  3  4
 |
2| 2  4  6  8
 |
3| 3  6  9 12
 |
4| 4  8 12 16
```

The unique numbers in the table are `1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16`. These are already sorted, so

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16
```

might be your exact output for N = 4. But since the sorting can be reversed and there's some leeway in the formatting, these would also be valid outputs:

```
[16,12,9,8,6,4,3,2,1]
```

```
1
2
3
4
6
8
9
12
16
```

```
16 12 9 8 4 3 2 1
```

## Test Cases

```
N=1 -> [1]
N=2 -> [1, 2, 4]
N=3 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9]
N=4 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
N=5 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 25]
N=6 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]
N=7 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 35, 36, 42, 49]
N=8 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 48, 49, 56, 64]
N=9 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 49, 54, 56, 63, 64, 72, 81]
N=10 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 49, 50, 54, 56, 60, 63, 64, 70, 72, 80, 81, 90, 100]
N=11 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 48, 49, 50, 54, 55, 56, 60, 63, 64, 66, 70, 72, 77, 80, 81, 88, 90, 99, 100, 110, 121]
N=12 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, 44, 45, 48, 49, 50, 54, 55, 56, 60, 63, 64, 66, 70, 72, 77, 80, 81, 84, 88, 90, 96, 99, 100, 108, 110, 120, 121, 132, 144]
```

Comment: So basically, the code returns a list of numbers in the multiplication table specified by N, except any number cannot be repeated?

Comment: How big can N be?

Comment: @xsot You can assume N*N will be less than your language's maximum usual int value (probably 2^31-1)

Comment: So essentially this is 1-n and non primes up to n^2.

Comment: @gregsdennis No. There are plenty of composites not present. e.g. 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96 for N = 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
S{*M^SQ2
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7B%2aM%5ESQ2&input=12&debug=0)

Explanation: `SQ` takes the evaluated list input (`Q`) and makes a list `[1, 2, ..., Q]`. `^SQ2` takes the Cartesian product of that list with itself - all possible product combinations. `*M` multiplies all these pairs together to form all possible results in the multiplication table and `S{` makes it unique and sorts it.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Input 5 already needs sorting, otherwise the 10 and 9 in the output are out of order.

Comment: darn keep on forgetting about that splatting on `M`. +1

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, <s>61</s> 51 bytes

```
lambda n:sorted({~(i%n)*~(i/n)for i in range(n*n)})
```

Thanks to xnor for shortening some syntax.

Comment: The `set(...)` can just be a set comp `{...}`. Also, functions are allowed by default here, so you can just write `lambda n:...`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about set comprehension, I completely forgot it existed.

Comment: I can't see a better way to do this, best I see with recursion is 56: `f=lambda n:n*[0]and sorted(set(range(n,n*n+n,n)+f(n-1)))`.

Answer (score 12):

## APL, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
{y[⍋y←∪,∘.×⍨⍳⍵]}
```

This is an unnamed monadic function. The output is in ascending order.

Explanation:

```
             ⍳⍵]}   ⍝ Get the integers from 1 to the input
         ∘.×⍨       ⍝ Compute the outer product of this with itself
        ,           ⍝ Flatten into an array
       ∪            ⍝ Select unique elements
     y←             ⍝ Assign to y
 {y[⍋               ⍝ Sort ascending
```

Fixed an issue and saved 2 bytes thanks to Thomas Kwa!

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(n)unique((a=1:n)'*a)
```

Answer (score 7):

## Julia, 24 bytes

```julia
n->sort(∪((x=1:n)*x'))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns an integer array.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(n::Integer)
    # Construct a UnitRange from 1 to the input
    x = 1:n

    # Compute the outer product of x with itself
    o = x * transpose(x)

    # Get the unique elements, implicitly flattening
    # columnwise into an array
    u = unique(o)

    # Return the sorted output
    return sort(u)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

Latest version with improvements proposed by @aditsu:

```
{)2m*::*0^$}
```

This is an anonymous function. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%0A%7B)2m*%3A%3A*0%5E%24%7D%0A~%60&input=5), with input/output code needed for testing it.

@Martin proposed another very elegant solution (`{,:)_ff*:|$}`) with the same length. I used the one by aditsu because it was much more similar to my original solution.

The main difference to my original solution is that this keeps the `0` value in the original sequence, which saves 2 bytes at the start. You'd think that this would not help, because you have to remove the `0` value from the result. But the core of @aditsu's idea is the `0^` at the end, which is a set difference with `0`. This removes the `0`, and at the same time, since it's a set operation, eliminates duplicate elements from the solution set. Since I already needed 2 bytes to eliminate the duplicates before, removing the `0` is then essentially free.

Explanation:

```
{     Start anonymous function.
  )     Increment to get N+1.
  2m*   Cartesian power, to get all pairs of numbers in range [0, N].
  ::*   Reduce all pairs with multiplication.
  0^    Remove 0, and remove duplicates at the same time since this is a set operation.
  $     Sort the list.
}     End anonymous function.
```

Comment: For the same length, `{2m*::)::*_&$}`, `{)2m*::*_&$0-}`

Comment: How about this for two bytes less :) `{,:)_ff*:|$}`

Comment: Another way: `{)2m*::*0^$}`

Answer (score 4):

## R, 39 bytes

```r
cat(unique(sort(outer(n<-1:scan(),n))))
```

This reads an integer from STDIN and writes a space delimited list to STDOUT.

We create the multiplication table as a matrix using `outer`, implicitly flatten into a vector and sort using `sort`, select unique elements using `unique`, and print space delimited using `cat`.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKM0L7OwNFWjOL@oREMjz9bQqjg5MU9DU1M1XzVPU1Pzv8l/AA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 24 bytes

```
@(n)unique((1:n)'*(1:n))
```

Comment: Good one! Soon it will be possible to do it [in 7 or 8 bytes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27181464#27181464)... :-)

Comment: Oooh, nice! :-)

Comment: @Luis have you tried [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64966/31516) in MATL?

Comment: I don't have much time now to read the whole challenge, but seeing your Matlab code it looks like it could be done with MATL

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
->n{c=*r=1..n;r.map{|i|c|=r.map{|j|i*j}};c.sort}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
->n {
  c=*r=1..n
  r.map { |i| c|=r.map{|j|i*j} }
  c.sort
}
```

Using nested loop to multiply each number with every other number upto n and then sorting the array.

**50 bytes**

```
->n{r=1..n;r.flat_map{|i|r.map{|j|i*j}}.uniq.sort}
```

**Usage:**

```
->n{c=*r=1..n;r.map{|i|c|=r.map{|j|i*j}};c.sort}[4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
```

Answer (score 4):

### zsh, <s>86</s> 56 bytes

*thanks to @Dennis for saving 30(!) bytes*

```bash
(for a in {1..$1};for b in {1..$1};echo $[a*b])|sort -nu
```

Explanation / ungolfed:

```bash
(                      # begin subshell
  for a in {1..$1}     # loop through every pair of multiplicands
    for b in {1..$1}
      echo $[a*b]      # calculate a * b, output to stdout
) | sort -nu           # pipe output of subshell to `sort -nu', sorting
                       # numerically (-n) and removing duplicates (-u for uniq)
```

This doesn't work in Bash because Bash doesn't expand `{1..$1}`—it just interprets it literally (so, `a=5; echo {1..$a}` outputs `{1..5}` instead of `1 2 3 4 5`).

Comment: I was waiting for a *sh answer. :D

Comment: [Relevant bash tip.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802) Seems to apply to the Z shell as well.

Comment: You can [squeeze a bit more out of brace expansions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65145/11259)

Answer (score 4):

## Shell + common utilities, 41

```bash
seq -f"seq -f%g*%%g $1" $1|sh|bc|sort -nu
```

---

Or alternatively:

## Bash + coreutils, 48

```bash
eval printf '%s\\n' \$[{1..$1}*{1..$1}]|sort -nu
```

Constructs a brace expansion inside an arithmetic expansion:

`\$[{1..n}*{1..n}]` expands to the arithmetic expansions `$[1*1] $[1*2] ... $[1*n] ... $[n*n]` which are evaluated and passed to `printf`, which prints one per line, which is piped to `sort`.

Careful use of quotes, escapes and `eval` ensure the expansions happen in the required order.

---

Or alternatively:

## Pure Bash, 60

```bash
eval a=($(eval echo [\$[{1..$1}*{1..$1}\]]=1))
echo ${!a[@]}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
OumΠπ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/378099yC8w1G////NzQAAA)

#### Explanation

```
OumΠπ2
    π2  cartesian square
  mΠ    map product
 u      unique
O       sort
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
import Data.List
f n=sort$nub[x*y|x<-[1..n],y<-[1..x]]
```

Usage example: `f 4` -> `[1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16]`.

`nub` removes duplicate elements from a list.

Edit: @Zgarb found a superfluous `$`.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 69 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...a=Array(i=n*n)].map(x=>a[q=~(--i%n)*~(i/n)]=q)&&a.filter(x=>x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoNADADA11QSYaN9QIRe/IT0EHRbUtasrlL04tdXPc/85C9Ln3RancXB55azcdMRkfArJdlB2UrDN40ywcaNdDMf4Jw@DMsDtLqMZywKoY@G1ac7bZj7aEsMnkL8QgvPGjGf)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n*n)].flatMap((_,i,x)=>x.every((_,j)=>~(j/n)*~(j%n)+~i)?[]:i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoMwEEDR0xRm1E51K0Tpxl1PICKDjZIQJiGK6Marp3b1ed/yzusUTdie4r86dSqJanoiesfIJ0gmONDsePtwABgLUxyomoP0ruP5H/bmBfYlmN15COaXwbYfapNXmCYvq3eanF@gg6pETD8)

No recursion like other answers

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
Union@@Array[1##&,{#,#}]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 17 bytes

```
t@<t:?,/t*\:t:1+!
```

Not much to say here. Sort (`t@<t:`) the unique items (`?`) of the flattened (`,/`) multiplied cartesian self-product (`t*\:t:`) of 1 up to and including N (`1+!`).

In action:

```
  t@<t:?,/t*\:t:1+!5
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 15 16 20 25
```

Answer (score 2):

### J, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

*Thanks to @Zgarb for -1 byte!*

```
/:~@~.@,@(1*/~@:+i.)
```

My first J answer! Golfing tips are appreciated, if there is something to golf.

This is a monadic function; we take the outer product by multiplication of the list `1..input` with itself, flatten, take unique elements, and sort.

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin, 70 bytes

```
val a={i:Int->(1..i).flatMap{(1..i).map{j->it*j}}.distinct().sorted()}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
val a: (Int) -> List<Int> = { 
    i -> (1..i).flatMap{ j -> (1..i).map{ k -> j * k } }.distinct().sorted()
}
```

Test it with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for(i in 1..12) {
        println(a(i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
řĐɐ*ƑỤş
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9weXT//8WZxJDJkCrGkeG7pMWf//8xMA)

```
ř           implicit input (n); push [1,2,...,n]
 Đ          duplicate
  ɐ*        generate multiplication table
    Ƒ       flatten array
     Ụ      get unique elements
      ş     sort in ascending order; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

```
R1+DZ!.PZU
```

##### Explanation

```python
R1+DZ!.PZUz:  # Implicit input                    Example (n=5)
R1+           # [1..input]                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   DZ!        # Cartesian product with itself     [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
      .P      # Product of each inner list        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
        ZU    # Uniquified                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 15, 16, 20, 25]
          z:  # And sorted                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 25]
              # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ɾẊƛΠ;Us
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuG6isabzqA7VXMiLCIiLCI2Il0=)

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4bqKds6gVXMiLCIiLCIxMCJd) for 5 or 4.25 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ṭẋ)ST
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4bms4bqLKVNU/8OHxZLhuZgpWf//MTI)

```
  )      For each x in 1 .. n:
Ṭ        Create a list containing 1 at index x and 0s before it,
 ẋ       and repeat it x times.
   S     Sum the results element-wise,
    T    and yield the indices of non-zeros in the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
⟦₁⟨∋×∋⟩ᵘo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aGh/NX/Goo/vwdCDxaP7Kh1tn5P//b/Y/AgA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦₁⟨∋×∋⟩ᵘo
⟦₁        Range from 1 to input number, inclusive
      ᵘ   Get all unique outputs of this predicate:
  ∋         Pick a number from that range
    ∋       Pick another number from that range
 ⟨ ×  ⟩      Multiply them together
       o  Sort the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 18 bytes

I remembered that I very conveniently implemented Cartesian products [before this question was posted](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang/commit/66aa714de8a284a1394d0152fb725ceca6d8e35c)!

```
1nLI20P[x*1R]sS$N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=1nLI20P%5Bx*1R%5DsS%24N%2E&input=12) (Outputs in reverse order.)

#### Explanation

```
1                     Push a 1 onto the stack
 n                    Take number from input (n)
  L                   Pushes 1,2,...,n onto the stack
   I                  Pushes length of stack so 0P knows how many items to pop
    2                 Pushes 2 (the number of repeats)
     0P               Essentially does itertools.product(range(1,n+1), 2)
       [              Open for loop that repeats n^2 times (0P puts this on the stack)
        x             Dump (I know each product has exactly two numbers
         *            Multiply
          1R          Rotate 1 step to the right
            ]         Close for loop
             s        Sort
              S       Remove duplicates ("set")
               $N.    Output whole stack as numbers and stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 10

```
S{m*Fd^SQ2
```

[Try it Online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7Bm%2AFd%5ESQ2&input=12&debug=0) or run a [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7Bm%2AFd%5ESQ2&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 96 bytes

```
i,a[1<<16];main(n){for(scanf("%d",&n);i<n*n;a[~(i%n)*~(i++/n)]="%d ");while(i)printf(a[i--],i);}
```

This prints the numbers in descending order. Suggestions are welcomed as this looks far from optimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), <s>37</s> 35 chars; 40 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Downgoat*

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing.

```
(b+r(1,+x¬)ßam(z=>z*l±s`,`.u¡s»l-i)
```

[Try it online!](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
(b+r(1,+x+1)m(#am(z=>z*l)))s(',').u()s(#l-i)
              // Implicit: x = input number
r(1,+x+1)     // Generate a range of integers from 1 to x.
m(#           // Map each item "l" in this range "a" to:
 am(z=>       //  a, with each item "z" mapped to
  z*l))       //   z * l.
(b+      )    // Parse this as a string by adding it to an empty string.
s(',')        // Split the string at commas, flattening the list.
.u()          // Take only the unique items from the result.
s(#l-i)       // Sort by subtraction; the default sort sorts 10, 12, 100, etc. before 2.
              // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: You can just use `r` instead of `A.r` for generating ranges

Comment: Sure this is 35 _bytes_? I get 35 chars or 40 bytes.

Comment: @manatwork This would be 35 bytes in the [ISO/IEC_8859-1 encoding format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). But I'm not sure that TeaScript supports that encoding, so I'll change it to 40 bytes for now.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```js
n=>eval(`for(r=[],a=n;a;a--)for(b=n;b;)~r.indexOf(x=a*b--)||r.push(x);r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)`)
```

### Explanation

```js
n=>eval(`                 // use eval to remove need for return keyword
  for(r=[],a=n;a;a--)     // iterate for each number a
    for(b=n;b;)           // iterate for each number b
      ~r.indexOf(x=a*b--) // check if it is already in the list, x = value
      ||r.push(x);        // add the result
  r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)      // sort the results by ascending value
                          // implicit: return r
`)
```

### Test

```html
N = <input type="number" oninput="result.innerHTML=(

n=>eval(`for(r=[],a=n;a;a--)for(b=n;b;)~r.indexOf(x=a*b--)||r.push(x);r.sort((a,b)=>a-b)`)

)(+this.value)" /><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 27 bytes

```perl6
{squish sort 1..$_ X*1..$_} # 27
{unique sort 1..$_ X*1..$_} # 27
{sort unique 1..$_ X*1..$_} # 27
```

Example usage:

```perl6
say {squish sort 1..$_ X*1..$_}(3); # (1 2 3 4 6 9)␤

my $code = {squish sort 1..$_ X*1..$_}

for 1..100 -> \N { say $code(N) }

my &code = $code;

say code 4; # (1 2 3 4 6 8 9 12 16)␤
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 51 bytes

```haskell
f n=[i|i<-[1..n*n],elem i[a*b|a<-[1..n],b<-[1..n]]]
```

Pretty boring. Just filters the list `[1..n*n]` to the elements of the form `a*b` with `a` and `b` in `[1..n]`. Using `filter` gives the same length

```
f n=filter(`elem`[a*b|a<-[1..n],b<-[1..n]])[1..n*n]
```

I tried for a while to generate the list of products with something more clever like `concatMap` or `mapM`, but only got longer results. A more sophisticated check of membership came in at 52 bytes, 1 byte longer, but can perhaps be shortened.

```
f n=[k|k<-[1..n*n],any(\a->k`mod`a<1&&k<=n*a)[1..n]]
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by using `(*)<$>..<*>..` like [this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6sybTRjfaUE8vTysvVic1JzVXIVNFQ0vTRsUOLBprowVlxP7PTczMU7BVKCjKzCtR0FNIA@Ki1MQUBVsbG4X01BLn/LyS1LyS4v8mAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## JAVA - 86 Bytes

```
Set a(int a){Set s=new TreeSet();for(;a>0;a--)for(int b=a;b>0;)s.add(a*b--);return s;}
```

---

## Ungolfed

```
Set a(int a){
    Set s = new TreeSet();
    for (;a>0;a--){
        for(int b = a;b>0;){
            s.add(a*b--);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 11 bytes

```
S{sm*RdSdSQ
```

This is similar to the Julia answer. Thanks to @Maltysen

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>74,73</strike> 70bytes

```
while($i++<$j=$n)while($j)$a[]=$i*$j--;$a=array_unique($a);sort($a);

print_r($a); // Not counted, but to verify the result
```

Ungolfed:

```
while($i++<$j=$n)
    while($j)
        $a[]=$i*$j--;
```

---

Previous:

<strike>`while(($j=$i++)<$n)for(;$j++<$n;)$a[]=$i*$j;$a=array_unique($a);sort($a);`</strike>

Not 100% sure what to do with output, but `$a` contains an array with the corresponding numbers. `$n` is the number geven via `$_GET['n']`, with `register_globals=1`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 57 bytes

`r=range(1,n+1);print(sorted({i*j for i in r for j in r}))`

Comment: You're not outputting the result. Wrap the `sorted` with a print and it'll be fine

Comment: I thought that's OK since default behavior of Python CLI is outputting the last command. It's my first CodeGolf, too.

Comment: By the way, where is the print here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65059/69669 ?

Comment: I know this is often confusing for new users but we allow functions as well as full programs. In that case, the line returns a function which can be used. However with what you had, the result wasn't going anywhere. We have a long meta discussion on it which can be found here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/32686

Comment: Also, I didn't notice the first time but you've got to do `n=in(input())` or `r=range(1,int(input())+1)` because we don't allow snippets in general. I'm sorry for all this no-fun stuff :(

Comment: OK, no problem, thanks for explanation :) I should have read meta firstly, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>13</s> <s>11</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
õ ï* Íâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDvKiDN4g&input=MTI)

```
õ ï* Íâ     :Implicit input of integer U
õ           :Range [1,U]
  ï         :Cartesian product with itself
   *        :Reduce each pair by multiplication
     Í      :Sort
      â     :Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 43 bytes

```
[ [1,b] dup outer [ ] gather natural-sort ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDsIwDET3foU/AKqCxFIEI4gBkEBMVQdT3BDROsFxB74@pKpYWM7SO9/pWmzUSbxdD6d9CT3qMxdkQwFeJEzdhJKIbRIMTtSygUDvgXgkXkj148Wy5o3j1hpg7Cl4/HNhne0u52OZshpgswWTmkkSzhZLqBazex2r6cJj8OAGTW4F9e@RUQfBbj5ugDr26GFVFGmgGMtjK@TxCw)

### Explanation

```
             ! 3
[1,b]        ! { 1 2 3 }
dup          ! { 1 2 3 } { 1 2 3 }
outer        ! { { 1 2 3 } { 2 4 6 } { 3 6 9 } }
[ ] gather   ! { 1 2 3 4 6 9 }
natural-sort ! { 1 2 3 4 6 9 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 52 bytes

```arturo
$[n][sort unique flatten map 1..n'x->map x..n=>[x*]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?wfSFST)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṗ€pUṠ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU5NiVFMiU4MiVBQ3BVJUUxJUI5JUEwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTAmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
Ṗ€pUṠ  # Implicit input
Ṗ      # Cartesian product
 €p    # Product of each
   U   # Uniquify the list
    Ṡ  # And sort it
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Google Sheets, 52 bytes

```cpp
=SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(N,N,LAMBDA(i,j,i*j)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, <s>124</s> 102 bytes

```
n=input()
l=[1]
for i in range(1,n+1):
 for j in range(1,n+1):l.append(i*j)
print sorted(list(set(l)))
```

More pythonic!

Comment: This is actually 123 bytes, not 124. But you can save a few bytes by using only a single space per indentation level rather than 4.

Comment: You can also put `l.append(i*j)` on the same line as the if conditional. I think it ends up being 102 bytes altogether.

Comment: And use `+=` instead of `append`.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman edited, thanks!

Comment: One relatively minor issue: `list(set(l))` is not guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies fixed (I think)

Comment: can't you use _ instead of n?

Comment: @anOKsquirrel i do not understand

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

```
n=>{n++;a=[];for(j=1;j<n;j++)for(i=1;i<n;i++)if(a.indexOf(i*j)<0)a.push(i*j);return a}
```

Looking to shorten it (maybe will try nesting loops).

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 91 bytes

```
for my $y (1 .. $ARGV[0]){
    map {$s{$n}++ unless($s{$n=$y*$_}) } ($y .. $ARGV[0])
}
print join(" ", sort {$a<=>$b} keys %s) . "\n";
```

to be run by passing the argument on the command line. It is quite a few declarations short of running with strictures and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 67 bytes

```
for$i(1..($n=pop)){$a{$_*$i}++for 1..$n}map say,sort{$a<=>$b}keys%a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 22 bytes

Input on stack

```
R0C(*=bA)bo(~Xe{|A?}x)
```

Long form:

```
range1
digit0
cart    # cartesian product of range0 and itself
while
  mult
  popA
  stack2
  pushA  # push products to second stack
endwhile
stack2
order
while    # loop to dedup
  peekA
  pushX
  equal
  if
    else
    pushA
    println
  endif
  XGetsA
endwhile
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 83 bytes

Here's a perl version that doesn't do a sort, and doesn't require duplicate removal.  I'd like to claim that makes it faster, but it's running time is actually O(n^2.5)

`$n=pop;for$i(1..$n*$n){for$j(1+int(($i-1)/$n)..sqrt($i)){if($i%$j==0){say$i;last}}}`

A one-character longer and much slower version of this same approach reads as follows:

```
$n=pop;
for $i (1..$n*$n) {
  for $j (1..$i) {
    if ($i%$j == 0 && $i <= $n*$j && $i >=$ j*$j) {
      say $i;
      last
    }
  }
}
```

It works by traversing the multiplication table in a strictly ordered fashion.

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog (SWI), 94 bytes

As the output only had to be in a reasonable format I've chosen to save 7 bytes by returning the list (which displays it), rather than doing an explicit write.

**Code:**

```
p(N,S):-findall(O,between(1,N,O),M),findall(Z,(member(X,M),member(Y,M),Z is X*Y),L),sort(L,S).
```

**Explained:**

```
p(N,S):-findall(O,between(1,N,O),M),                      % Get a list of numbers between 1 and N.
        findall(Z,(member(X,M),member(Y,M),Z is X*Y),L),  % Create a list of the products of the different combinations of elements in the list of numbers between 1 and N. 
        sort(L,S).                                        % Sort and remove doubles
```

**Example:**

```
p(6,L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 30, 36]
```

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/FoQuiAlD.pl)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
×þµFṢQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394@uF9h7a6Pdy5KPD///@GBgA)

There are so many different ways to do this in 6 bytes that it feels like 5 might be possible. I haven't found a way, though.

### Explanation

```
×þµFṢQ
×þ        Form multiplication (×) table (þ) up to the input
  µ       Fix a parsing ambiguity (µ in Jelly is like parentheses in C)
   F      Flatten the table into a single continuous list
    Ṣ     Sort the elements of the list
     Q    Take the unique elements of the sorted list
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, <s>146</s> <s>137</s> <s>133</s> 87 bytes

```swift
var t={n in Set((1...n).map{i in(1...n).map{(i,$0)}}.joined().map{$0.0*$0.1}).sorted()}
```

To run, paste this into a playground or the REPL and call `t(_:)`.

Here's an expanded version:

```swift
func table(n: Int) -> [[Int]] {
   let range = 1...n

   let combos = range.map { i in
      range.map { j in
         (i, j)
      }
   }.joined()

   let products = combos.map { combo in
      combo.0 * combo.1
   }

   let uniques = Set(products)
   let sorted = uniques.sorted()
   return sorted
}
```

Let's run through this step by step. We'll assume that `n` is 4.

First, we create a closed range containing all the numbers from 1 to `n`, inclusive. So, `range` is set to `1...4`. (In the golfed version, it's more efficient to just create the range twice.)

Now we `map` over `range` twice, one `map` inside the other. This effectively creates a nested array containing every permutation of two numbers within the range `1...n`. We then join these arrays to remove the nesting. For our example, this sets `combos` to

```swift
[
   (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
   (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4),
   (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4),
   (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)
]
```

(In actuality, it's a `FlattenSequence` instead of an `Array`, but that doesn't matter for what we're going to do with it.)

Next, we `map` over `combos`, returning the results of multiplying each tuple's elements together. (Using tuples instead of more arrays saves 2 bytes due to the shorter element access syntax.) This sets `products` to

```swift
[
   1, 2, 3, 4,
   2, 4, 6, 8,
   3, 6, 9, 12,
   4, 8, 12, 16
]
```

We then create a `Set` from this array. `Set`s are unordered, and can only contain one of each item. This enables us to concisely remove duplicate products, at the cost of losing the order of the products. For all intents and purposes, this sets `uniques` to

```swift
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16].shuffled()
```

Finally, we call `sorted()` on `uniques` to get our ordering back, and return the result, which is

```swift
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
```

By default, `sorted()` does the same thing as `sorted(by: <)`, which sorts in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 29 bytes

```
⊼∘⊙∘∊∘[$(⌼ *) #0 #0]∘$(+ 1)∘⍳
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIWSpaUlaboWNw0fde151DHjUddMENnRBSSjVTQe9exR0NJUUDYAoligkIqGtoKhJkhF72aIxi2aXBqZ-VblRZklqTl5CholCpaamhCpBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 34 characters

```
[range(1;.+1)*range(1;.+1)]|unique
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ jq --compact-output '[range(1;.+1)*range(1;.+1)]|unique' <<< 5
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,20,25]
```

(`range()` not generates array — “The numbers are produced as separate outputs.” Found no way to multiply a range's output by itself.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVXD0FpP21BTC5kTW1Oal1lYmvr/vykA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 57 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZPNSsNAFIUX7rrzDS5ZJZL-TP6aii247KJu6i4Eic2kHY2T2Nz-gPgkbrrRjU9Un8Y7JmBTBS2IEEju5ZzvnDDJ00sxidLIfg20psxW0Vxq4fYsu77hE4RRJCTwNXIZF3Ce5_DQaAAsoxSSU9CHEvuDoYz5msdjfh_QHBrQf15g0vS3Pdkf6AwwA2m0kjTCUZTrYmd3p-aTK8NoxaJAISfYKrI58rgEvB0dU1a7DZe8QMAZh2RBGpFJWAmcfWymYsml6rPgBWQJXJAjnwuJqdQTnVHG7RhpnupaoJlQXaFmGAocsLCmt37Um2CZ4NRd9u9cNhlN8Ezo1e3OgXafCCYwWjGvTnIPIbm7sE4FdBWURDRbbh3u_RWc-VWAo0LIQc_23pt0Dw_rfslzvslkn7mWX2WrDqRx1MnunY3_nz2snS6dqo-vOhGadh59do_ln7HZlPd3)

```scala
n=>(1 to n).flatMap(i=>(1 to n).map(i*_)).distinct.sorted
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vZRBT9swGIYvO_VXvOqpnUIhaVoyBAfEAXFgh7Fb1UPWfC7uEjvYDhRN_SW7cIEftV_D5zRQApO2SogoB9vf-z7v5zjy7wc7S_N0eHd3Xzmxk_z5dK5_LGjmcJ5KBVo6UpnFcVniV6cDZCQgeuoAZ8r1D3BsTHo74fEURywAP7u7ONHKOlMxJMW3VM0JwugCIZyGuyRIVVauFl-nOZZsrUuqswEUrKBarHlgUBqdeaAWrL-R7hLSWcrFM0UzRWjTNAFIHO5g2UwWm8kKt5LyjOufsXgOPCVXh1VKXlUEyqkg5SxSlcFqUxeLWqwHmbROqpkb-AJlA6frr8DVlecx7TvZNU5UrJNarTv2K3N5Tco3XJH1m_nKjtJI5XLVE72wPyh-Xjiez3vdSTdA8067_b4HT8JpSx_9Ux8gChC3XcP_cw3ZGGAc4EvbHm9pT5gQIOSlcNwmjbYhjV7C9hrgyENZxPNo1IaP3wseJk1A7EPYwePhq53sbx-2_yYv_ktmuMmNkibb98Ca2J_sq7NJPrKP6EUve00_ie-J0bw25t9utb5Vmsvl6ZJ5BA)

```scala
def f(n: Int): Array[Int] = {
    // Construct a Range from 1 to the input
    val x = 1 to n

    // Compute the outer product of x with itself
    val o = for {
      i <- x
      j <- x
    } yield i * j

    // Get the unique elements and sort them
    o.distinct.sorted.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 61 bytes

```perl
map{//;map$a{$'*$_}++,1.."@F"}1..$_;say for sort{$a-$b}keys%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaX98aSKkkVquoa6nE12pr6xjq6Sk5uCnVAmmVeOvixEqFtPwiheL8opJqlURdlaTa7NTKYtXE//8NDf7lF5Rk5ucV/9f1NdUzMDQA0j6ZxSVWVqElmTm2pXmZhf91E/NyAA)